# Extending a virtual product Magento

Tags: magento, extend, product, mage

I am trying to make a custom product type. I extend the virtual product type.
I can add the product in the backend of Magento and it will be added. However.. It does not mather which producttype I extend, I always see the 'simple' product design. Better would be a virtual product design.

**config.xml**

```
<catalog>
        <product>
            <type>
                <iasoproduct translate="label" module="catalog">
                    <label>Iaso Product</label>
                    <model>iasoproduct/product_type_iaso</model>
                    <is_qty>1</is_qty>
                    <index_data_retreiver>iasoproduct/catalogIndex_data_iaso</index_data_retreiver>
                    <price_model>iasoproduct/product_price</price_model>
                    <composite>0</composite>
                </iasoproduct>
            </type>
            </product>        
    </catalog>
```

**Data\Iaso.php**

```
class Zimzap_IasoProduct_Model_CatalogIndex_Data_Iaso extends Mage_CatalogIndex_Model_Data_Virtual
{
    public function getTypeCode()
    {
        return Zimzap_IasoProduct_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_IASO_PRODUCT;
    }
}
```

**Product\Type\Iaso.php**

```
class Zimzap_IasoProduct_Model_Product_Type_Iaso extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Virtual
{


}
```

**Product\Price.php**

```
class Zimzap_IasoProduct_Model_Product_Price extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price
{

}
```

**Product\Type.php**

```
class Zimzap_IasoProduct_Model_Product_Type extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Virtual
{
    const TYPE_IASO_PRODUCT = 'iasoproduct';
}
```

What do I miss?!??

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View::initProductLayout($product, $controller)` method, you will see how magento adds an additional layout update handle in the layout. So, you have to create a new layout update with `PRODUCT_TYPE_iasoproduct` handle. Have a look at `catalog.xml` layout, you can find `PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable` handle here, use it as a reference to create your own layout update.